# Finder seems to be broken, Desktop files missing

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

I have an old imac mid 2010 with upgraded ram and ssd that works really well. I mostly use it for coding and I did not updated / installed any new apps lately.

Since 24hours ago:

- finder seems to be broken (cannot launch it)
- cannot access the cmd+space finder
- all files in desktop disappeared

Everything else seems to be working. The computer seems to be fine except that. I have access to chrome, spotify, terminal etc through the shortcuts clicking on the bottom menu bar.

Following some instructions, I have tried to locate ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist and there is nothing.

I would like to understand what is happening and fix it. I have run:

```
sudo sysdiagnose -f ~/Desktop
```

Here is the result https://pastebin.com/ehp52jBR

Comment: According to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6897345, a Timemachine backup would be a solution - no backups on this old imac

Comment: I'd go with a straight overwrite of the OS from Recovery as first step; nothing should be lost... hopefully...

Comment: I can confirm the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist is there on High Sierra. Since this is a user folder Do you have another User to try with.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, I have Verified the disk on Recovery, everything was okey. Clicked on repair even it showed nothing to repair. I do not have the CD with the OS, how can I do the OS overwrite? could you point out to some instructions? Checked on google, but I think I do not have the right answer. Many thanks

Comment: Do it from Recovery - Cmd/R at the chimes, Reinstall macOS; it will overwrite the OS but not the data.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tetsujin. I will update when finished.

Answer (score 1):

Massive thanks to @Tetsujin. It worked.

Just a small tip if you experience the same issue, the re-install seemed to be stuck at '*1 minute remaining*'. I dug a little bit and the system was copying everything from a temp folder to the final destination.

You can activate the logs by pressing Cmd/L or just wait until it finishes (it can take several hours/days).